# Voltage adjustment

Tags: voltage, pcb, voltage-regulator

I want to connect external flash memory like this one here: 
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/macronix/MX25L25735FZ2I-10G/1092-1152-ND/4211595
to a soc nRF52832. The chip itself works with supply voltage from 1.7V to 3.6V,
and flash with 3V. What is the best solution to connect these two? How to adjust voltages. Im a begginer so the only thing that comes to my mind is using voltage divider, or voltage regulator. But I can't decide what is a better option.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 1.7V to 3.6V?

Comment: Yes, Im sorry. My bad.

Comment: can you actually add meaningful tags? [tag:pcb] has nothing todo with your question? Also, **edit** your question to correct your voltage mistake!

Comment: Wow, alright. Just don't get mad. I'm sorry, I'm new..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run them both at 3.3V. These are both standard parts (the flash chip is 2.7V to 3.6V) and that's a very standard voltage. They both have LVCMOS outputs/inputs, so you will need no level translation or anything like that between them.

As for getting 3.3V, you should use regulator. Resistor dividers and the like do not work for power supplies going to power-hungry things like flash chips and bluetooth radios.

This nRF52832 breakout board from Sparkfun has a 3.3V regulator already installed: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13990

The sparkfun breakout board has a pin or two that outputs the regulated 3.3V that you can also send to the flash chip.

Here's a breakout board that should hopefully fit the flash chip: https://www.tindie.com/products/DrAzzy/breakout-board-for-dfnmsopwsonvqfn-16-3-pack/

Answer (score 0):

All chips are specified to run with a range of voltages.  As long as there is one voltage for which the ranges overlap, you just run both of them at that voltage.  In this case, it looks like you can just run them both at 3V.  This is actually a simplified answer in that with different logic families you could have logic threshold issues, but it is usually true for straight LVCMOS type I/Os.

It is only if the voltage ranges don't overlap that you need to do some kind of translation.  In that case, the best way to do the translation depends on particular type and voltage of the pins.